# trigger with no name on sqlite_trace callback function

Tags: triggers, sqlite, trace

The observations below is on a large sized sqlite3 database.

Setup:
I have a view which has a trigger for udpate of a field. This trigger of this view has multiple update statements on different underlying tables. These tables also have triggers for update of respective fields.

Also, there is a registered callback using sqlite_trace method on our production code. This method only prints the activity on this given database.

Observations:

1. When this view is updated for this given field, it updates the field of underlying tables.
2. Update of field on underlying tables trigger their respective triggers.
3. The registered callback method is called which prints that TRIGGER is called on the database with trigger name.

**However, there are some triggers with no names. Or the callback method prints just TRIGGER without name. For example :**

-- Update View V1

-- TRIGGER T1

-- TRIGGER T2

**-- TRIGGER**

-- TRIGGER T3

**-- TRIGGER**

-- TRIGGER T4

My question is : **What are these un-named triggers ?** When are they called ? Is this because some fields have UPDATE RESTRICT / DELETE RESTRICT / CASCADE on the tables ?  I was unable to get any information from these triggers. Just trying to solve the mystery of these un-named triggers.

Comment: Nobody here knows what triggers you have defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The un-named triggers are because of the referential integrity ( foreign key ) relationship of one table with another table.

**Steps to reproduce:**

**Step1 :** Create two tables where one table references other table and create some test rows in these tables. T1 can have CASCADE OR RESTRICT for delete or update.

```
CREATE TABLE T (id NUMBER);
CREATE TABLE T1 (id NUMBER REFERENCES T (id) DELETE (CASCADE/RESTRICT) UPDATE ( CASCADE /RESTRICT ));
```

**Step 2:** Write a test C++ program that creates a sqlite3 connection. Refer https://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html for more on SQLite C/C++ Interface.

**Step 3:** Enable following using sqlite3_exec

```
PRAGMA FOREIGN_KEY=ON .
```

**Step 4:** Register a callback with sqlite3_trace that prints the query in the callback. Refer : https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/profile.html

**Step 5:** Call execute method to update id of table T.

**Output:** Above statement will execute UPDATE of table T and on referenced tables of T. In this case, its T1. The update on table T1 generates un-named trigger and a callback is generated on sqlite3_trace. The sql in callback has no information about this trigger and hence output is as below , i.e. trigger with no name:

```
TRIGGER -
```

> **Conclusion :** The un-named triggers are seen because of the foreign key relationship. When a referenced table is modified, its associated
>   tables are attempted to change causing un-named triggers in sqlite3_trace callbacks.
>
> **Note :** There will be an un-named trigger for each reference. So, if a field is referenced in n tables , you will see n un-named
>   triggers and n callbacks on sqlite3_trace. Also, the database should
>   have PRAGMA FOREIGN_KEY ON so that it enforces referential integrity.
>   You will not see this behavior if PRAGMA FOREIGN_KEY is OFF ( 0 ).